# How to retrieve a field from a LinkedList?

Tags: java, sqlite, linked-list

Eclipse: Neon.2 (4.6.2) | Java: jre.8.0_121 | SQLite: sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1.jar

I have created a LinkedList into which I have loaded the records from an SQLite table.  (Why I need a LinkedList is another issue.)  My question is how can I retrieve a specific field value from a specific row (element) of the LinkedList?  I have created a method I called "getStr" in the masterRec class and can retrieve a field from the LinkedList using

```
for (masterRec masterRec : masterList) {
    System.out.println(recCount+": "+ masterRec.getStr("StdPubNum"));
}
```

However, this retrieves the "StdPubNum" field for ALL the records in the list.  I don't know how to retrieve **one field** for a **single record** without using the for loop.  Help is appreciated.

Comment: You can call `masterList.get(index)`. But using an `ArrayList` would be a lot more efficient for that.

Comment: as above `masterList.get(index).getStr("StdPubNum")`

Comment: How do you determine which row is the specific one? D you have some key?

Comment: Thanks @Scary Wombat.  Your suggestion did the trick.  I couldn't get the syntax correct.

Comment: @TheBakker, I grab the index from the count as I traverse through the LinkedList.

Comment: Ok well then if you just going by index @ScaryWombat code is the way to go